# C++11 (g++ thread sanitized) Ordering nonatomic operations with atomics (false positive?)

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, thread-sanitizer

I am experimenting with g++ and thread sanitizer and I think I am getting false positives. Is this true, or am I making some big mistake?

Program (cut&paste from Anthony Williams: C++ Concurrency in Action, page 145, listing 5.13)

```
#include <atomic>
#include <thread>
#include <assert.h>
bool x=false;
std::atomic<bool> y;
std::atomic<int> z;
void write_x_then_y()
{
  x=true;
  std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_release);
  y.store(true,std::memory_order_relaxed);
}
void read_y_then_x()
{
  while(!y.load(std::memory_order_relaxed));
  std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_acquire);
  if(x)
    ++z;
}
int main()
{
  x=false;
  y=false;
  z=0;
  std::thread a(write_x_then_y);
  std::thread b(read_y_then_x);
  a.join();
  b.join();
  assert(z.load()!=0);
}
```

Compiled with:

```
g++ -o a -g -Og -pthread a.cpp -fsanitize=thread
```

g++ version

```
~/build/px> g++ -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/6.1.1/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-redhat-linux
Configured with: ../configure --enable-bootstrap --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,fortran,ada,go,lto --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --with-bugurl=http://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-checking=release --enable-multilib --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-linker-build-id --with-linker-hash-style=gnu --enable-plugin --enable-initfini-array --disable-libgcj --with-isl --enable-libmpx --enable-gnu-indirect-function --with-tune=generic --with-arch_32=i686 --build=x86_64-redhat-linux
Thread model: posix
gcc version 6.1.1 20160621 (Red Hat 6.1.1-3) (GCC)
```

I am getting:

```
~/build/px> ./a
==================
WARNING: ThreadSanitizer: data race (pid=13794)
  Read of size 1 at 0x000000602151 by thread T2:
    #0 read_y_then_x() /home/ostri/build/px/a.cpp:17 (a+0x000000401014)
    #1 void std::_Bind_simple<void (*())()>::_M_invoke<>(std::_Index_tuple<>) /usr/include/c++/6.1.1/functional:1400 (a+0x000000401179)
    #2 std::_Bind_simple<void (*())()>::operator()() /usr/include/c++/6.1.1/functional:1389 (a+0x000000401179)
    #3 std::thread::_State_impl<std::_Bind_simple<void (*())()> >::_M_run() /usr/include/c++/6.1.1/thread:196 (a+0x000000401179)
    #4 <null> <null> (libstdc++.so.6+0x0000000baaae)

  Previous write of size 1 at 0x000000602151 by thread T1:
    #0 write_x_then_y() /home/ostri/build/px/a.cpp:9 (a+0x000000400fbd)
    #1 void std::_Bind_simple<void (*())()>::_M_invoke<>(std::_Index_tuple<>) /usr/include/c++/6.1.1/functional:1400 (a+0x000000401179)
    #2 std::_Bind_simple<void (*())()>::operator()() /usr/include/c++/6.1.1/functional:1389 (a+0x000000401179)
    #3 std::thread::_State_impl<std::_Bind_simple<void (*())()> >::_M_run() /usr/include/c++/6.1.1/thread:196 (a+0x000000401179)
    #4 <null> <null> (libstdc++.so.6+0x0000000baaae)

  Location is global 'x' of size 1 at 0x000000602151 (a+0x000000602151)

  Thread T2 (tid=13797, running) created by main thread at:
    #0 pthread_create <null> (libtsan.so.0+0x000000028380)
    #1 std::thread::_M_start_thread(std::unique_ptr<std::thread::_State, std::default_delete<std::thread::_State> >, void (*)()) <null> (libstdc++.so.6+0x0000000badc4)
    #2 main /home/ostri/build/px/a.cpp:26 (a+0x000000401097)

  Thread T1 (tid=13796, finished) created by main thread at:
    #0 pthread_create <null> (libtsan.so.0+0x000000028380)
    #1 std::thread::_M_start_thread(std::unique_ptr<std::thread::_State, std::default_delete<std::thread::_State> >, void (*)()) <null> (libstdc++.so.6+0x0000000badc4)
    #2 main /home/ostri/build/px/a.cpp:25 (a+0x00000040108a)

SUMMARY: ThreadSanitizer: data race /home/ostri/build/px/a.cpp:17 in read_y_then_x()
==================
ThreadSanitizer: reported 1 warnings
```

I got this warning in more complex program, and I've thought it is my bug, but now even a "school book program" displays the same behaviour.
Is it (i.e. some compiler switch is missing) me or g++?

**UPDATED**
Taken from [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37552866/why-does-threadsanitizer-report-a-race-with-this-lock-free-example)

```
#if defined(__SANITIZE_THREAD__)
#define TSAN_ENABLED
#elif defined(__has_feature)
#if __has_feature(thread_sanitizer)
#define TSAN_ENABLED
#endif
#endif

#ifdef TSAN_ENABLED
#define TSAN_ANNOTATE_HAPPENS_BEFORE(addr) \
    AnnotateHappensBefore(__FILE__, __LINE__, (void*)(addr))
#define TSAN_ANNOTATE_HAPPENS_AFTER(addr) \
    AnnotateHappensAfter(__FILE__, __LINE__, (void*)(addr))
extern "C" void AnnotateHappensBefore(const char* f, int l, void* addr);
extern "C" void AnnotateHappensAfter(const char* f, int l, void* addr);
#else
#define TSAN_ANNOTATE_HAPPENS_BEFORE(addr)
#define TSAN_ANNOTATE_HAPPENS_AFTER(addr)
#endif

#include <atomic>
#include <thread>
#include <assert.h>
bool x=false;
std::atomic<bool> y;
std::atomic<int> z;
void write_x_then_y()
{
  x=true;
  std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_release);
  TSAN_ANNOTATE_HAPPENS_BEFORE(&x);
  y.store(true,std::memory_order_relaxed);
}
void read_y_then_x()
{
  while(!y.load(std::memory_order_relaxed));
  std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_acquire);
  TSAN_ANNOTATE_HAPPENS_AFTER(&x);
  if(x)
    ++z;
}
{
  x=false;
  y=false;
  z=0;
  std::thread a(write_x_then_y);
  std::thread b(read_y_then_x);
  a.join();
  b.join();
  assert(z.load()!=0);
}
```

Compile command

```
g++ -o a -g -Og -pthread a.cpp -fsanitize=thread -D__SANITIZE_THREAD__
```

Comment: Isn't your release fence in wrong place?

Comment: I've changed the book reference. Now it points to the right example. The example is cut&paste. If the fences are in the wrong place they are in the wrong place in the book also. ;-) Where would you put the release fence?

Comment: I think I found the answer in [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37552866/why-does-threadsanitizer-report-a-race-with-this-lock-free-example)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**TL;DR:** This is a TSAN false positive. The code is valid.

Thread 1:

```
  x=true;                                              // W
  std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_release); // A
  y.store(true,std::memory_order_relaxed);             // X
```

Thread 2:

```
  while(!y.load(std::memory_order_relaxed));           // Y
  std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_acquire); // B
  if(x)                                                // R
     ++z;
```

[[atomics.fences]/2](http://eel.is/c++draft/atomics.fences#2):

> A release fence A synchronizes with an acquire fence B if there exist
>   atomic operations X and Y, both operating on some atomic object M,
>   such that A is sequenced before X, X modifies M, Y is sequenced before
>   B, and Y reads the value written by X or a value written by any side
>   effect in the hypothetical release sequence X would head if it were a
>   release operation.

Let's go through the list:

- [✔] "there exist atomic operations X and Y, both operating on some atomic object M": obvious. M is `y`.
- [✔] "A is sequenced before X": obvious ([[intro.execution]/14](http://eel.is/c++draft/intro.execution#14) for those who want a citation).
- [✔] "X modifies M": obvious.
- [✔] "Y is sequenced before B" : obvious.
- [✔] "and Y reads the value written by X...": that's the only way that loop could terminate.

Therefore, the release fence A synchronizes with the acquire fence B.

The write W is sequenced before A, and the read R is sequenced after B, therefore W *inter-thread happens before*, and so *happens before*, R. [[intro.races]/9-10](http://eel.is/c++draft/intro.races#9):

> An evaluation A *inter-thread happens before* an evaluation B if
>
> - A synchronizes with B, or
> - A is dependency-ordered before B, or
> - for some evaluation X
>
>   - A synchronizes with X and X is sequenced before B, or
>   - A is sequenced before X and X inter-thread happens before B, or
>   - A inter-thread happens before X and X inter-thread happens before B.
>
> An evaluation A *happens before* an evaluation B (or, equivalently, B
>   *happens after* A) if:
>
> - A is sequenced before B, or
> - A inter-thread happens before B.

There is no data race because of the happens-before relationship ([[intro.races]/19](http://eel.is/c++draft/intro.races#19)):

> The execution of a program contains a *data race* if it contains two
>   potentially concurrent conflicting actions, at least one of which is
>   not atomic, and neither happens before the other, except for the
>   special case for signal handlers described below. Any such data race
>   results in undefined behavior.

Moreover, the read R is guaranteed to read the value written by W, because W is the *visible side effect*, there being no other side effect on `x` after the threads started ([[intro.races]/11](http://eel.is/c++draft/intro.races#11)):

> A visible side effect A on a scalar object or bit-field M with respect
>   to a value computation B of M satisfies the conditions:
>
> - A happens before B and
> - there is no other side effect X to M such that A happens before X and X happens before B.
>
> The value of a non-atomic scalar object or bit-field M, as determined
>   by evaluation B, shall be the value stored by the visible side effect
>   A.

Comment: detailed explanation

Answer (score 1):

`memory_order_relaxed` imposes no restraints on reordering.

`memory_order_acquire` doesn't prevent reordering past the fence from above. It only prevents ordering from below. This means that the code can be executed as if:

```
std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_acquire);
if(x)
  ++z;
while(!y.load(std::memory_order_relaxed));
```

This will cause a data race as the read in `if(x)` races with `x=true`.

You need fences with `memory_order_acq_rel` or `memory_order_seq_cst` semantics in both functions which prevents reordering in both directions.

Comment: A bit inaccurate. An operation with **acquire** semantics prevents moving **subsequent loads** prior to it. An operation with **release** semantics prevents moving **preceding stores** past it.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin That would not be correct according to my understanding. Here is an argument from authority: http://preshing.com/20120913/acquire-and-release-semantics/ that argues that any operation, not just load or store, cannot float across a barrier. I would love to read an argument that supports your claim.

Comment: What Preshing says disagrees with the [C++ standard](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order). I would say Preshing underspecified the effects.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin That is not the C++ standard. Please post the exact reference to the paragraph in the standard and the standard version.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin I cannot find citations from the link you posted in the actual C++ standard.

Comment: Can you find them in Preshing's blog post?

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin Therefore you don't have an argument backing your claim. As I have said, my argument is from authority. Here is another expert: https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/Cpp-and-Beyond-2012-Herb-Sutter-atomic-Weapons-1-of-2 saying that fences prevent read and write orderings.

Comment: Sutter's video actually gets them right, I was about to recommend watching it. In full though.

Comment: As with _argument is from authority_, I find C++ reference more authoritative than Preshing.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin Where in the talk does Herb support you claim?

Comment: I suggest you a file a bug report to [C++ reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/) if you think it is wrong.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin While this discrepancy is interesting, it doesn't influence the example OP cited. Either way, the example is causing a data race.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin But see Herb Sutter's comments under Pershing's post. Also we are talking about fences here, which are subtly different from plain store-release on atomic objects (which is what cppreference is aiming at, I think). Personally, I find it easier to just reason about whether there is a happens-before relationship than reordering.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately ThreadSanitizer cannot comprehend memory fences. This is because it reasons in the terms of happens-before relation between accesses to certain objects, and there's no object in the fence operation.

If you replace the relaxed load + acquire fence with an acquire load, and the release fence + relaxed store with a release store, TSan would correctly detect the happens-before relation between the store and the load.

Also note GCC's TSan implementation may fail to instrument atomics at O0 (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/42905055/234420).