# TSAN data-race reported when two classes refer to each other via weak_ptr

Tags: c++, c++17, clang, smart-pointers, thread-sanitizer

I'm using clang++ with LLVM17. I have two classes `Foo` and `Bar` that both refer to each other via a weak_ptr data member. There are multiple threads that can get copies of shared_ptr<Bar> objects. Sometimes, TSAN will report a data-race while one thread is destroying its copy of the `std::shared_ptr<Bar>` object.

Here is my example code and I've annotated where TSAN is reporting issues:

```
class Bar;
class Foo : public std::enable_shared_from_this<Foo> {
public:
    std::shared_ptr<Bar> get_instance() {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lck(m_);

        std::shared_ptr<Bar> sh = _ptr.lock();
        if (sh) {
            return sh;
        } else {
            sh = std::make_shared<Bar>(weak_from_this());
            _ptr = sh; // <<<<
        }
        return sh;
    }

private:
    std::weak_ptr<Bar> _ptr;
    std::mutex m_;
};

class Bar {
public:
    Bar(std::weak_ptr<Foo> ptr) : _ctx(ptr) {}
private:
    std::weak_ptr<Foo> _ctx;
};

void get_and_release(std::shared_ptr<Foo> aP) {
    for (int i=0; i<1000; i++) {
        std::shared_ptr<Bar> p = aP->get_instance(); // <<< During d'tor
    }
}

int main() {
    std::shared_ptr<Foo> aP = std::make_shared<Foo>();
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;
    for (int t=0; t<4; t++) {
        threads.emplace_back(get_and_release, aP);
    }
    for (auto& thread : threads) {
        thread.join();
    }
}
```

When multiple threads call `get_and_release()` at the same time, TSAN reports the following race:

```
WARNING: ThreadSanitizer: data race (pid=21947)
  Write of size 8 at 0x7b0c00001800 by thread T2 (mutexes: write M0):
    #0 operator delete(void*) ../lib/tsan/rtl/tsan_new_delete.cpp:126:3 (example+0xea98e)
    #1 void std::__1::__libcpp_operator_delete[abi:ue170006]<void*>(void*) ../llvm-17.0.6-n6964152/include/c++/v1/new:278:3 (example+0xed245)
    #2 void std::__1::__do_deallocate_handle_size[abi:ue170006]<>(void*, unsigned long) ../llvm-17.0.6-n6964152/include/c++/v1/new:302:10 (example+0xed1c1)
    #3 std::__1::__libcpp_deallocate[abi:ue170006](void*, unsigned long, unsigned long) ../llvm-17.0.6-n6964152/include/c++/v1/new:318:14 (example+0xed0da)
    #4 std::__1::allocator<std::__1::__shared_ptr_emplace<Bar, std::__1::allocator<Bar> > >::deallocate[abi:ue170006](std::__1::__shared_ptr_emplace<Bar, std::__1::allocator<Bar> >*, unsigned long) ../llvm-17.0.6-n6964152/include/c++/v1/__memory/allocator.h:130:13 (example+0xed03e)
    #5 std::__1::allocator_traits<std::__1::allocator<std::__1::__shared_ptr_emplace<Bar, std::__1::allocator<Bar> > > >::deallocate[abi:ue170006](std::__1::allocator<std::__1::__shared_ptr_emplace<Bar, std::__1::allocator<Bar> > >&, std::__1::__shared_ptr_emplace<Bar, std::__1::allocator<Bar> >*, unsigned long) ../llvm-17.0.6-n6964152/include/c++/v1/__memory/allocator_traits.h:288:13 (example+0xecfc5)
    #6 std::__1::__shared_ptr_emplace<Bar, std::__1::allocator<Bar> >::__on_zero_shared_weak() ../llvm-17.0.6-n6964152/include/c++/v1/__memory/shared_ptr.h:332:9 (example+0xecc7c)
    #7 std::__1::weak_ptr<Bar>::~weak_ptr() ../llvm-17.0.6-n6964152/include/c++/v1/__memory/shared_ptr.h:1777:19 (example+0xed786)
    #8 std::__1::enable_if<__compatible_with<Bar, Bar>::value, std::__1::weak_ptr<Bar>&>::type std::__1::weak_ptr<Bar>::operator=<Bar>(std::__1::shared_ptr<Bar> const&) ../llvm-17.0.6-n6964152/include/c++/v1/__memory/shared_ptr.h:1836:5 (example+0xebf37)
    #9 Foo::get_instance() A.cc:18:18 (example+0xeb5c7)
    #10 get_and_release(std::__1::shared_ptr<Foo>) A.cc:37:38 (example+0xeb305)

  Previous read of size 8 at 0x7b0c00001800 by thread T1:
    #0 std::__1::__shared_count::__release_shared[abi:ue170006]() ../llvm-17.0.6-n6964152/include/c++/v1/__memory/shared_ptr.h:172:9 (example+0xed8f0)
    #1 std::__1::__shared_weak_count::__release_shared[abi:ue170006]() ../llvm-17.0.6-n6964152/include/c++/v1/__memory/shared_ptr.h:213:27 (example+0xed889)
    #2 std::__1::shared_ptr<Bar>::~shared_ptr[abi:ue170006]() ../llvm-17.0.6-n6964152/include/c++/v1/__memory/shared_ptr.h:772:23 (example+0xeb6d6)
    #3 get_and_release(std::__1::shared_ptr<Foo>) A.cc:38:5 (example+0xeb313)
```

As far as I can tell this should be safe since every thread holds copies of the smart pointers. What am I misunderstanding here?

I attempted to change the `std::weak_ptr<Foo> _ctx` in `Bar` into a `std::shared_ptr<Foo>` instead, but it didn't fix the issue entirely. However, changing it into a `std::shared_ptr<Foo>` has made the data-race less likely.

Comment: TSAN discovers the data race because `get_instance()` handles smart pointers as guarded by the mutex, and `get_and_release()` destroys smart pointers unguarded.

Comment: @273K - Could you explain further, please? It looks like every smart pointer is a copy and the control block of each should be thread-safe per the standard, right? Thus, I'm not sure how one thread could read the same address as another is potentially writing here.

Comment: No, the control block is not thread safe, only the counters there are thread safe.

Comment: I'm not sure how this program even compiles, seeing as it's manipulating `Bar` while it's still an incomplete class, when only the forward declaration has been seen. See whether the behavior changes if you move the implementation of `Foo::get_instance` out of class, below the definition of `Bar`.

Comment: @273K For what it's worth, I don't see a data race here. It's legal for two threads to concurrently access or modify two distinct instances of `std::shared_ptr`, even when they point to the same object. It would be a race to concurrently modify the same instance - but I don't see that happening in the code shown.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik This is a usual TSAN report when it sees some storage once accessed while a mutex is locked, and another time accessed w/o a mutex lock. See `(mutexes: write M0):` in the thread T2 and no mutex mentioned in the thread T1.

Comment: @273K I understand this is what TSAN reports. I don't understand **why** it so reports. Far as I can tell, by the rules of the C++ language the program shown is race-free. (Except that I still don't understand how it manages to create an instance of an incomplete class. I suspect the problem has something to do with that.)

Comment: @IgorTandetnik There is no difference in the behavior when I move `get_instance()` to under `Bar`.

Comment: So apparently TSAN [can report false positives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37552866/why-does-threadsanitizer-report-a-race-with-this-lock-free-example) when synchronization is performed via atomic counters. Here, it reports a race between `std::shared_ptr` destructor in `get_and_release` decrementing a counter in the control block, and `_ptr = sh;` assignment deallocating the now-abandoned control block. But the whole reason that assignment is deallocating the control block is because it observed that decrement, and noticed that the strong counter reached zero.